# CSS small issue, wordpress site>elementor template

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

My website has a white stripe[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueCw2.jpg) on the middle of the home page that I can't get rid of. Help please!! I don't have elementor pro

Comment: need to see which element has this line, and after that rewrite the styles in the css file and everything will work

Or perhaps there is an empty section that creates this line,  need to look at the code
But you did not provide anything other than a screenshot, this will not help solve your problem in any way, but how to do it I wrote above

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.